# Where to handle the error in a sequelize ORM query statement?

Tags: javascript, express, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize ORM in Node/Express.

I have two tables, User and Item. Item has a foreign key linked to UserId.

When I try to create an Item with a UserId that is invalid (not present in Users table) a "SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError" is thrown and leads to crashing of the application due to unhandled.

The problem I have is this:

Where do I handle the error?

Here is my code.

```
.post(function(req,res){
        models.Item.create({
            title : req.body.title,
            UserId : req.body.UserId
        }).then(function(item){
            res.json({
                "Message" : "Created item.",
                "Item" : item
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: See https://sequelize.org/v3/api/errors

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you want to handle the specific error, attach a `.catch` handler

```
models.Item.create({
  title : req.body.title,
  UserId : req.body.UserId
}).then(function(item){
  res.json({
    "Message" : "Created item.",
    "Item" : item
  });
}).catch(function (err) {
  // handle error;
});
```

If you want to handle errors more generally (i.e. show a nice error message, instead of killing your server, you might want to have a look at unhandledexception

https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception

If you are using express, it also contains some error handling facilities http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

Comment: If you want to catch the specific SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError error you can pass it to the catch function

`.catch(Sequelize.SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError, function (err) {
  // handle onky foreign key errors ;
});`

Comment: is it possible to handle all ORM errors by HTTP 500 status and default error handler in express? actually i don't want to add `.catch(err=>{next(err)});` whenever I hit the database.

Comment: please add the await version try { ... } catch(err) { ... }

Answer (score 5):

You can handle all ORM errors to return an HTTP 500 status and some default error message by doing something like below

```
router.use((error, request, response, next) => {
  response.status(error.status || 500).json({
    status: 'error',
    error: {
      message: error.message || serverErrorMsg,
    },
  });
});
```

The above code also allows you to throw errors with custom messages that will be sent to the client by passing the error to the `next` function

```
const error = new Error(/* your error message */);
error.status = 409;
next(error);
```